# System.Net.WebRequest Custom Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, httpwebresponse

Trying to follow this MSDN tutorial to get a web response but not getting any response back, so wondering if I can use anything else except default or network credentials for sending a web request.

I am using it in a Sharepoint Custom Timer Job installed using a Feature Receiver, here's the code,

Timer Job class with execute method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EmailJob.FeatureCode
{
    class SharePointWarmupJob : SPJobDefinition
    {
        private const string JOB_NAME = "Email Job";

        public SharePointWarmupJob() : base() { }

        public SharePointWarmupJob(SPWebApplication webApp)
            : base(JOB_NAME, webApp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {
            this.Title = JOB_NAME;
        }

        public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false);

            if (this.WebApplication.Sites.Count > 0)
                WarmUpSharePointSite(this.WebApplication.Sites[0]);
        }

        private void WarmUpSharePointSite(SPSite siteCollection)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(siteCollection.Url);
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.Method = "GET";

            System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Feature Receiver class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using EmailJob.FeatureCode;

namespace EmailJob
{
    class EmailJobFeature : SPFeatureReceiver
    {
        private const string JOB_NAME = "Email Job";

        public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void FeatureUninstalling(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
            if (webApp == null)
                throw new NotImplementedException("Error obtaining reference to Web application");

            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webApp.JobDefinitions)
                if (job.Name == JOB_NAME) job.Delete();

            SharePointWarmupJob warmupJob = new SharePointWarmupJob(webApp);

            SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
            schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
            schedule.EndSecond = 59;
            schedule.Interval = 5;

            warmupJob.Schedule = schedule;

            warmupJob.Update();
        }

        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
            if (webApp == null)
                throw new NotImplementedException("Error obtaining reference to Web application");

            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in webApp.JobDefinitions)
                if (job.Name == JOB_NAME) job.Delete();

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to debug, it gives no response back at code line

```
"System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();"
```

This is my VPC and am logged as Administrator, I even commented out credentials code line or tried network credentials but it just doesn't seems to work.

Oh yes when i try to test code in Console app, it says the credentials properties are null except encrypt = true

Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx), Credentials is of type `ICredentials` so you need an implementation.

Fortunately, they also state you should use a [NetworkCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) object or [CredentialCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.aspx) ;)